# Can cursor based pagination be used for SEO?

Tags: duplicate-content, security, pagination

We have a category page which may contain hundreds of thousands of posts. We want to paginate these results using cursor based pagination.

The base page may look like:

```
www.example.com/topic/category
```

This page will have two links at the bottom:

```
Previous -> null

Next -> www.example.com/topic/category?before=SOME_ENCRYPTED_ALPHANUMERIC_STRING_HERE
```

A few pages down the lane might have these links:

```
Previous -> www.example.com/topic/category?after=SOME_ENCRYPTED_ALPHANUMERIC_STRING_HERE

Next -> www.example.com/topic/category?before=SOME_ENCRYPTED_ALPHANUMERIC_STRING_HERE
```

However, in this strategy, it would lead to a large number of links as the content moves around due to more content being generated everyday. It will also lead to duplicate content, as multiple links may point to a bucket of content that was already covered in some other URL.

Does this mean cursor based pagination cannot be used effectively for SEO ?

If yes, does exposing your API with just a `page` parameter a good practice ? (as it will make it very easy for anyone to crawl the data)

Comment: What does "cursor based pagination" mean and where did you pick up the term?

Comment: https://jsonapi.org/profiles/ethanresnick/cursor-pagination/

Comment: I doubt Google cares about JSON programming techniques.

Comment: [Pagination of any type is bad for SEO and rarely used by visitors](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/123637).

Answer (score 1):

This would seem to be a way to burn up your link budget and dilute your keywords for the page, so likely not a great idea.

I can't see how "exposing your API" can help with SEO - Google would not recognise how to use an API, nor would it help Google in finding your content.